# eventOpenTrigger runs every time change is happening to live event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Goal is to add attendees synchronously into Calendar Event being created. I can add attendees just fine to Event, however, when as a user I am changing any conference data of Event manually (e.g. add attendee manually or put Location), it's going to run "eventOpenTrigger" again, even if a new event is not opening.

Appscript.json below:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "",
      "logoUrl": "",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomePage_noevent",
      }
    },
    "calendar": {
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE",
      "name": "",
      "logoUrl": "",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomePage_noevent"
      },
      "eventOpenTrigger":{
        "runFunction": "onHomePage" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want this to happen because I don't want my Add on to go to `onHomePage` while user manually changes any info of event.

Workaround I have tried: I have also tried to completely remove `eventOpenTrigger`, and just try and check if there is a live event being created while the Add On is running, but I can't figure out how to do that either. I would prefer if `eventOpenTrigger` just function as normal and only got triggered when an event was opened, and not every time the opened event's details change.

Comment: As stated in the documentation of [eventOpenTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventopentrigger), it will execute a function when a user opens a Calendar event for viewing or editing. Manually editing an event requires you to open the event which satisfy the condition to execute the evenOpenTrigger.

Comment: I understand that, but if the event is already open, why would manually editing an event rerun eventOpenTrigger while the event is already open? If the case is like this, then eventOpenTrigger and eventUpdateTrigger are basically the same thing.